# why is my regex find returns false?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this code with following params:

```
    private int getIdFromUrlByRegex(String regex) {
        String url = webDriver.getCurrentUrl();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
        return m.find() ? Integer.valueOf(m.group()) : 0;
    }


url1 = https://mysite/providers/224/billing_details
```

url2 = https://myysite.com/providers/224

```
regex = "(?<=providers/)\d+"
```

for url1 it evaluate:

m.find() == false

and the method returns 0 instead of 224

for url2

m.find() == true

and the method returns 224

Comment: Just swap `regex` and `url`. `Pattern.compile` accepts pattern and `Pattern.matcher` accepts the matching line.

Comment: You swapped regex and url. url should be `https://biz-test.waze.com/providers/224/billing_details`, regex should be `(?<=providers/)\d+`

Comment: it was correct in code. I did the mistake here in the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is also working fine.

sample code:

```
String url = "http://biz-test.waze.com/providers/224/billing_details";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=providers/)\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
if(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group()); //224
}
```

It's working. [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qX5bD7/1)

---

Capture it at group 1 by enclosing `\d+` inside the parenthesis `(\d+)`

sample code:

```
String url = "http://biz-test.waze.com/providers/224/billing_details";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=providers/)(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
if(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // 224
}
```